# unable to open VS 2015 Project in VS 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I want to open to a project in VS 2017 which is created in VS 2015, but when ever i want to open VS 2017 restarts everytime. Please help me.

Comment: An update to VS2017 was pushed last week, it included solution loading fixes. (See [the release notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#mar28).)

Comment: I have updated to latest build also. but same problem persists @Richard

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for some of them my other solution(answered before) didn't work. then I have updated my SQL server Data tools to 15.x , now the problem is completely fixed.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. followed the instruction from this [tutorial](https://www.jonashendrickx.com/2017/06/26/cannot-open-ssrsssis-projects-vs2017/) and it is solved.

Method 2

1. Close all windows and instances of ‘Microsoft Visual Studio 2017‘.
2. Download ‘Microsoft Reporting Services Projects‘ from the Visual Studio marketplace.
3. Open your solution or project.
4. try to reload project after opening solution